# How to create a dynamic DataFrame to export multiple data to excel with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a function that return some values:

```
def sigInput(audio):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return [mean, total, power]

data1 = sigInput('sound1.wav')
data2 = sigInput('sound2.wav')
data3 = sigInput('sound3.wav')
data4 = sigInput('sound4.wav')


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mean': [data1[0], data2[0], data3[0], data4[0]],
    'total': [data1[1], data2[1], data3[1], data4[1]],
    'power': [data1[2], data2[2], data3[2], data4[2]],
    'label': ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
})

df.to_excel('expData.xlsx')
```

Based on the code above, data1, data2, data3, and data4 will have three values according to what the function returns. My target is I want to export these data to excel using pandas.

If I have more than four data, maybe 10 or 20 data, then I have to write the `DataFrame` manually.

My question is how to make the contents in the `pd.DataFrame` more dynamic if it has a lot of data?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
data = [sigInput(f'sound{i}.wav') for i in range(1, 5)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).assign(label=[f'data{i}' for i in range(1, 5)])
df.columns = ['mean', 'total', 'power', 'label']
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but I got this error:
`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements`

Comment: @NgrWisnu How about with `df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_axis(['mean', 'total', 'power'], axis=1).T.assign(label=[f'data{i}' for i in range(1, 5)])`

Comment: I got another error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 10 elements, new values have 3 elements`

is the error from the set_axis?

Comment: @NgrWisnu How about `df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.set_axis(['mean', 'total', 'power', 'label'], axis=1).assign(label=[f'data{i}' for i in range(1, 5)])`

Comment: `ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (10)`

Comment: @NgrWisnu I mean `df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.set_axis(['mean', 'total', 'power', 'label'], axis=1).assign(label=[f'data{i}' for i in range(1, 5)])`

Comment: I do not know, I've run the code with `df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.set_axis(['mean', 'total', 'power', 'label'], axis=1).assign(label=[f'data{i}' for i in range(1, 5)])` but still got this error `ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (10)`

Comment: @NgrWisnu How about just `df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.assign(label=[f'data{i}' for i in range(1, 5)])`

Comment: still not works, but when I delete the .T it works.

Comment: @NgrWisnu Ah yes! that's the trick, that was my next suggestion :)

Comment: That's why I like to write long code, because not easy to become a oneliner:D

Comment: @NgrWisnu Yeap :) anyway now it should be much more efficient than long code

Comment: @NgrWisnu This solution is more scalable than others, others are all very manual :P

Comment: but with this code, the name of the columns is the index of the returns. How to set the column name?

Comment: @NgrWisnu What do you want the column name to be?

Comment: when it return the mean, I want to set the column name to Mean or Mean Value, if it returns the total maybe I can set the column name to Total Value, etc

Comment: yeah it works, but .T should be deleted, at least for my condition

Comment: @NgrWisnu Oh yes edited mine, feel free to mark

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary containing the label name and the data and use it while creating the dataframe like this:

````
data_dict = {"data1":data1,"data2":data2,"data3":data3,"data4":data4,"data5":data5}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'mean': [x[0] for x in data_dict.values()],
    'total': [x[1] for x in data_dict.values()],
    'power': [x[2] for x in data_dict.values()],
    'label': [x for x in data_dict.keys()]
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Write a for loop to create that list of list and then pass it into the dictionary.

```
s = [data1,data2,data3]
for i in range(len(s)):
    d = s[i]
    for j in range(0,4):
        d = d[j]
```

You can append the last d in a list or so and then pass on